# Second level relationships (similar to Rails's has_many :through)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the below model setup (irrelevant parts removed):

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="vehicles")
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Chip(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Is there a simple way to get all Chips belonging to a specific Client (through the Vehicle table)?
Something similar to `has_many :through` in Rails?

Like to be able to call sth like:

```
client = Client.objects.first()
chips = client.chips.all()
```

[EDIT] Adding more info for context

View:

```
class ClientDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Client

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        section = self.kwargs['section']
        context['section'] = section
        if section == 'chips':
            context['chips'] = Chip.objects.filter(
                vehicle__client=self.get_object())
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.kwargs['section'] == 'vehicles':
            return ('clients/client_vehicle_list.html',)
        elif self.kwargs['section'] == 'chips':
            return ('clients/client_chip_list.html',)
        return ('clients/client_detail.html',)
```

ulrconf:

```
    path('clients/<int:pk>/', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(),
         name='client-detail', kwargs={"section": None}),
    path('clients/<int:pk>/vehicles/', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(),
         name='client-detail', kwargs={"section": "vehicles"}),
    path('clients/<int:pk>/chips/', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(),
         name='client-detail', kwargs={"section": "chips"}),
```

Templates are split across multiple files, but here's the most important one:

```
// client_chip_list.html
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

{% include 'section_title.html' with icon='bi-building' title=client %}

{% include 'clients/client_detail_tabs.html' %} // used to switch between sections (templates)

{% include 'chips/chip_table.html' with chips=chips %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should make filtering on `Chip` model, so `Chip.objects.filter(vehicle__client=specific_client_instance)`, then you can access everything from this queryset.

Comment: @SunderamDubey so basically to get access to this in a detail template I would need to modify `get_context_data` in the client detail view (DetailView) and add sth like `context['chips'] = Chip.objects.filter(vehicle__client=self.get_object())`. Is this correct?

Comment: So, you have made different templates for different kwargs.

Comment: yes.

the question is - is it a good design to modify get_context_data this way, or maybe it's better to define a chips() method (or property) on the client model?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting that on the model, to keep the view slim:

```
class Client(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def chips(self):
        return Chip.objects.filter(vehicle__client=self)
```